# $output = to return some HTML and PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Advanced custom fields to display team bios using a shortcode, the client came back to me and wants to have a custom image size that is then masked via CSS.

It was working fine until I tried to add the custom image. using wp_get attachment_src, I am sure I am making an obvious PHP erro, can you help me trouble shoot,

the code is:

```
function team_profiles_func($atts) {
        global $post;
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'id' => $post->ID
        ), $atts));
        if (get_field('team_profiles')) {
            while (has_sub_field('team_profiles')) {
                $attachment_id = get_sub_field('employee_photo');
                $size = "team";
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );

                $output .= '<div class="crew-wrap media">';
                $output .= '    <a class="crew-img" href="#">';
                $output .= '    <img src="'.echo $image[0].'" class="media-object" alt="">';
                $output .= '    </a>';
                $output .= '    <div class="media-body">';
                $output .= '        <h2 class="media-heading">'.get_sub_field( 'employee_name').'</h2>';
                $output .= '        <h4 class="media-heading">'.get_sub_field( 'employee_title').'</h4>';
                $output .= '        <p>'.get_sub_field( 'employee_bio').'</p></div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }
```

Comment: What is `$image` if you do a `var_dump()`?

Comment: it was working until.. so ok, but what happenede then? what is the output? What did you expect, what did you actually see, hwat did the error_log say, what did you debug as @putvande says, etc etc. Consult yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

`echo` is a language construct and does **NOT** have a return value:

```
$output .= '    <img src="'.echo $image[0].'" class="etc...
                            ^^^^---incorrect
```

That `echo` will directly dump the value in `$image[0]` as output, and you end up generating

```
<img src="" class=" etc...
```

You should have

```
$output .= '    <img src="'. $image[0] .'" class=" etc..
```

Note the lack of echo.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$size` variable can either be a string keyword (thumbnail, medium, large or full) or a 2-item array representing width and height in pixels, e.g. array(32,32). What do you mean by `"team"`?

Answer (score -1):

You can't output PHP from a PHP script, and have it executed. PHP is executed on the webserver. So the client does not know what to do with it.

Instead try this:

```
$output .= '    <img src="' . $image[0] . '" class="media-object" alt="">';
```

Comment: You can do that but it will only display <?php echo "foo"; ?> and not foo.

Comment: you do not see any difference between `output` and `execute`?